# Android: Show/Hide Status bar when new Notification Arrived

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

My application should run in full screen mode. And also i have to show notification bar when new items arrived to my app from our server. I write coding for notification in BroadcastReceiver class. i would like to make a decision in MainActivity like show the status bar only when new notification received otherwise hide the status bar. All are done when app is in foreground.

Coding for Notification:

```
Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context,Activity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, scheduledIntent, 0);

                nm = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                CharSequence from = "From address";
                CharSequence message = "New Orders received";
                Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Hai", System.currentTimeMillis());
                notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, pendingIntent);
                notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                nm.notify(uniqueID, notif);
                notif.ledOnMS = 500;
                notif.ledOffMS = 500;
```

Through this code notifications are recieved. But the status bar is always visible. I need to hide when no notification received.
Please provide me the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: i also faced same prob from past 2days,but finally i got it by righting code like this..

Comment: once check my  answer i have edited  sridhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OnCreate() method you have to write this one:

```
 AppPreferences prefs = new AppPreferences(PresentChatActivity.this);
             boolean notify_checkbox = prefs.getNotifyState();

    Notification(message.getBody(),fromName, name);
```

Then, outside OnCreate(), write this function

```
   protected void Notification(String body, String fromName, String Notificationmsg) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);      

    String tickerText = getString(R.string.app_name, body);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PresentChatActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


     notif.setLatestEventInfo(PresentChatActivity.this,Notificationmsg, message, pendingIntent);
     notif.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), fromName, body,pendingIntent );  
     notificationManager.notify(10001, notif);
     }
```

Comment: what is notify_checkbox and chat_data

Comment: its nothing but we notification check box then ckeck box have check only the notification wil dispaly,otherwise notification wont display

Comment: in ur progrmm no need to check and unchecked means u can add directly like this  Notification(message.getBody(),fromName, name);

Comment: cant understand your logic. i dont have any checkbox in my app, the thing is show/hide status bar

Comment: ho kkk just simply u want to display notoficationaaa??tel me this clearly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16398/discussion-between-sridhar-and-shassss)

Comment: Ok good, but i need to show/hide the status bar, you can see my code for creating notification, it was working good and status bar is always visible.

Comment: I need to hide the status bar if no notification received

Comment: i need like some NotificationManager for detecting new notification received

Comment: write this in ur code to hide status bar                       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

Comment: ok, so notify_checkbox will true when new notification received right

Comment: I write code for Notification in BroadcastReceiver class onReceive() method ok. shall i write in onCreate(){ AppPreferences prefs = new AppPreferences(PresentChatActivity.this);
             boolean notify_checkbox = prefs.getNotifyState();

Comment: AppPreferences is in which package. i am using android 4.03

Comment: u have to create new pakageeee for dat...nd iam using 2.2

Comment: My team lead, ask me to drop notification functionality